# D3 charts bar spacing issue

Tags: d3.js, charts

In D3 charts v4 .how do i maintain white spaces constant in between the bars ?﻿
Can you please  explain clearly what is totalBarWidth and totalBar? we need to fix the x value to come bars side by side without more than 10px between two bars and maximum no.of bars are 10, more than 10 will not come. In my application if there is only two bars i want to align side by side with bar width like 25px and 10px space between two bars but now if there are only two bars width of the bar is increasing, if i give the bar width like 25px, width is changing but how to change the x value to decrease the space between bars(They are align like,  first one is at starting and second one is at middle of the bandWidth())

Comment: Looks like a description of some of the Christmas Puzzles

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking about here. You should [edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, show your [mcve], and tell us what results you get.

Comment: Did you try `paddingInner()` method ?